Flask Google sing in - protected routes still accessible after logout
I'm working on a Flask project, where I have implemented Google sign in option using authlib and also using Flask SocketIO to send and recieve data from server to browser and from browser to server asynchrously, but i'm facing an issue, everything is working ok, but after sign in with google when we hit the logout it logs the user out but after that if i try to access the protected route (which is /scan in my case) we are able to do as we have a session under cookies in browser.

The expected behaviour is when a user logged out he shouldn’t be able
to acces the protected route directly by entering the url.

Below is what i have implemented:
Project Structure:
.PROJECT_DIR


config.py
run.py
-app



—routes.py


—models.py


---init.py

run.py:
from app import create_app, socketio
# from app.auth_routes import auth

app = create_app()
# app.register_blueprint(auth)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting Flask-SocketIO server with logging enabled...")
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, log_output=True)

config.py:
from datetime import timedelta
import os

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    
    # Database configuration
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or 'sqlite:///sqlite3.db'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

    # Enable secure cookies for session handling
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'  # Can also be 'Strict' depending on the level of protection you want
    SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'  # Store session data in the filesystem
    SESSION_PERMANENT = False
    PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(minutes=2)
    SESSION_USE_SIGNER = True

    
    # Google OAuth Config
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID')
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET')
    OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT = os.environ.get('OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT') or '1'
    GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:5000/login/callback'

    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

app/init.py:
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_login import LoginManager
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
from flask_session import Session

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
socketio = SocketIO(manage_session=False)
login_manager = LoginManager()
oauth = OAuth()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')
    # os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

    # Initialize extensions
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    socketio.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    Session(app)
    login_manager.login_view = 'main.login'
    login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
    
    # OAuth configuration for Google login
    oauth.init_app(app)
    #Register google outh
    oauth.register(
        name='google',
        server_metadata_url='https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration',
        # Collect client_id and client secret from google auth api
        client_id= “MY_CLIENT_ID",
        client_secret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
        client_kwargs={
            'scope': 'openid email profile'
        }
    )


    # Register Blueprints
    from .routes import main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    # Error handlers
    @app.errorhandler(500)
    def internal_error(error):
        return f"500 Error: {error}", 500

    @app.errorhandler(404)
    def not_found_error(error):
        return f"404 Error: {error}", 404

    return app

from .models import User  # Import after initializing app

# User loader for Flask-Login
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

app/routes.py:
from flask import Blueprint, app, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, request, session, make_response
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth, OAuthError
import requests
from . import db, socketio, oauth
from .models import User
from flask_socketio import disconnect
import nmap


main_bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main_bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


# routes to handle socketIO connect/disconnect
user_sid_map = {}

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        user_sid_map[current_user.get_id()] = request.sid  # Store sid for the current user
        print(f"User {current_user.get_id()} connected with sid {request.sid}")

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        print(f"User {current_user.get_id()} disconnected.")
        user_sid_map.pop(current_user.get_id(), None)  # Remove sid when the user disconnects



@main_bp.route('/scan')
@login_required
def scan():
    print(f"Current session: {session}")
    print(f"Current user: {current_user}")
    session.modified = True  
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return socketio.emit('scan_error', {'error': 'User is not Authorized!'})
    response = make_response(render_template("scan.html"))
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
    return response

@main_bp.route('/login')
def login():
    redirect_uri = url_for('main.authorize', _external=True)
    google = oauth.create_client('google')
    return google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)


@main_bp.route('/login/callback')
def authorize():
    try:
        """Google login page will apear in this will provide you with 
        information of user"""
        token = oauth.google.authorize_access_token()
        # print(f'token: {token}')
        user_info = token['userinfo'] # This is the dict for userinfo
        # print(f'user info: {user_info}')
        #user will return a dict of info like: email = user.get("email")
        #Save the user info to database and login the user

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=user_info['email']).first()
        if not user:
            user = User(email=user_info['email'], name=user_info['name'])
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for('main.scan'))
    except Exception as e:
        # print(f"Exception: {e}")
        flash('You are not logged in successfully, try again!')
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))


@main_bp.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    session.clear()
    response = make_response(redirect(url_for('main.index')))
    response.set_cookie('session', '', expires=0)
    response.set_cookie('remember_token', '', expires=0)
    return response


@socketio.on('start_scan')
def handle_scan(data):
    # rest of the logic

